# Difference between sip proxy and sip outbound proxy?

Tags: voip, sip

What is the basic difference between a sip proxy and a sip outbound proxy. Can sip proxy and outbound proxy be the same?

Answer (score 1):

A sip outbound proxy is a sip proxy, but just given a more specific name/role. The outbound proxy is set on the user agent for all outbound calls. A generic sip proxy could be used for routing between service providers, carriers, etc. Or it could be used as an outbound proxy for certain devices. For reference:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP+outbound+proxy

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP+proxy